# How to move the allocator object in a container class move constructor

Tags: c++, allocator, move-constructor

I'm implementing a ring buffer container class:

```
template <class T, class A = std::allocator<T>>
class ring {
private:
    size_type cap_;  // the capacity of the array
    alloc_type alloc_;  // the allocator
    pointer array_;
    ...  
public:
    ring(size_type n, const alloc_type &a = alloc_type()) : cap_{n}, alloc_{a}, array_{alloc_.allocate((size_t)cap_)}, ... {
       memset(array_, 0, (size_t)cap_ * sizeof(T));
    }
    ...
};
```

(I have not shown the typedefs here, but they're obvious.)

I'm not sure how to write the move constructor so that it handles the allocator correctly, but I imagine it's similar to dealing with a typical pointer to a dynamically allocated resource. In this case, I must transfer ownership of the allocator to the new container, and then (possibly?) make the original allocator safe, such that it'll not trigger the destruction of the resource when it goes out of scope?

```
ring(self_type&& other) : cap_{other.cap_}, alloc_{other.alloc_}, ... {      
other.alloc_ = ???  // must I do something with the other's allocator as I would with a pointer to heap memory?
}
```

Comment: You could wrap the allocated memory in a `shared_ptr` and make a custom deleter.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect to get. "Yes, you need to make the allocator transfer safe"? There is nothing in the standard that says how _your_ objects should look after being moved-from (it of course specifies that for the standard library types, but only those). So there is no concrete answer we can give you with the code you show. For starters, we would need to know what restrictions you intend to place on `A` (the allocator) and what operations you intend to be valid on your container in a moved-from state.

Comment: I'm expecting the moved-from ring object to be garbage, which is what I usually expect from moved-from objects. I simply want to know what I should do to the moved-from allocator, and nothing else.